# xcode: Mysql connector library not work on iphone5 (armv7s) ,any solution?

Tags: mysql, ios, xcode

I built my App using **Mysql Connector/C** to connect a remote Mysql database, its works fine on the simulator (no errors, no warnings) but when i try to run it on my device (iphone5) i got this error:

**No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=armv7 armv7s, VALID_ARCHS=armv7 armv7s)**

i tried -as in some answers- to change setting (Architectures - Build Active Architectures- Valid Architectures) but the error still, only when i change the setting (Architectures & Valid Architectures) to "armv6" its build without error but many warnings appears says:

**warning: no rule to process file '(my App dir)/main.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6**

and also for all .m files, when i tried to start the App i got message:

**Xcode cannot run using selected device**

I know that the Connector library need to update , but are there any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your need compile the connector lib in xcode for iOS (armv6, armv7, armv7s, i386), then use lipo tool to combine output libs.

direct connect your mysql in app is not safe, a suggest way is setup a Apache+PHP+MySQL server, then on iPhone useing ASIHTTPRequest to connect your server.

Comment: When i tried to compile i got somthimg like this: libmysqlclient.dylib, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): Mobile/mysql-connector-c-6.0.1-osx10.4-x86-32bit/lib/libmysqlclient.dylib Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:

Comment: you need download mysql client library source, compile it to a static library for iOS device

Comment: You are right! i got your advice using PHP, its even faster!! Thanks